# Disabled other select if value equal to 1

Tags: jquery

I have dynamic select option. Only 0 and 1 user can select.

If user select value = 1, I want disable other select & keep current.

If user select value = 0 from current option so other select enable again.

HTML

```
A : 
<select name="quantity[1]" class="form-control quantity trigger">
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
</select>
B : 
<select name="quantity[2]" class="form-control quantity trigger">
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
</select>
C:
<select name="quantity[3]" class="form-control quantity trigger">
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
</select>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).on('change keyup keypress', '.trigger', function() {
  $(".quantity").prop("disabled", true);

  $('.quantity option:selected').each(function() {
    quantity += parseInt($(this).val()) || 0;
    if (quantity == 1) {
      $(this).prop("disabled", false);
    } else {
      $(this).prop("disabled", true);
    }
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qq1q6orw/2/

Comment: What is the issue ?

Comment: All select disable. So I can't change the option

Comment: you want the drop down which is selected to 1 should remain active and all others are disabled and when you select 0 all should remain active correct ?

Comment: Yes. It's correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of unnecessary selectors and there's unnecessary logic in your posted code. You can simply tell jQuery not to disable the active select using [.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/)

```js
$(document).on('change keyup keypress', '.trigger', function() {

  var quantity = $(this).val();
  if (quantity == 1) {
    $('.quantity').not(this).prop("disabled", true);
  } else {
    $('.quantity').not(this).prop("disabled", false);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
A :
<select name="quantity[1]" class="form-control quantity trigger">
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
</select>
B :
<select name="quantity[2]" class="form-control quantity trigger">
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
</select>
C:
<select name="quantity[3]" class="form-control quantity trigger">
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a sample example:

```js
$(document).on('change keyup keypress', '.trigger', function() {
  var flag = $(this).val() == 1;
  $(".quantity").not(this).prop("disabled", flag);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
A :
<select name="quantity[1]" class="form-control quantity trigger">
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
</select> B :
<select name="quantity[2]" class="form-control quantity trigger">
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
</select> C:
<select name="quantity[3]" class="form-control quantity trigger">
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

here is updated fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/8sbk4dgo/1/

```
$(document).on('change keyup keypress', '.trigger', function() {
    if($(this).val() == 1){
      $(".quantity").not(this).prop("disabled", true);
    }else{
    $(".quantity").prop("disabled", false);    
    }     

    $('.quantity option:selected').each(function() {
        var quantity = parseInt($(this).val());
        if (quantity == 1) {
            $(this).prop("disabled", false);
        } else {
            $(this).prop("disabled", true);
        }
    });
});
```